# How can I find the duplicated elements in a array and replace them?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my first time on the website. I have a big problem with my hangman.

I have a wordBank:

```
       wordBank = ["pizza", "pie", "cookie", "candy", "salad", "chicken", "pork", "burger", "fries"]
```

I have a variable that chooses a random word from the wordBank and makes it into a array:

```
randomChosenWord = wordBank[round(random(wordBank.length - 1))].split('')
```

And I have a array that is gets pushed with a amount of placeholders the same as the length of my randomly chosen word. If I press my button object [I have many from A-Z] , it will replace the placeholder thats in the same index as the letter in the randomly chosen word with the letter on the button:

```
 this.click = function() {
            if (mouseX > this.x - 10 && mouseX < this.x + 10 && mouseY > this.y - 10 && mouseY < this.y + 10) {
                if (randomChosenWord.includes(this.letter)) {               
                lettersChosen.splice(randomChosenWord.indexOf(this.letter), 1, this.letter)
                }
```

An Example:
Pizza is the randomly chosen word

The array that keeps track of the letters i choose is displayed as " - - - - - " (Same length as pizza)

If I press the button that says z, it will replace the index which is the same as the index that has the first z in the randomly chosen word. This will display " - - z - - "

**This works well but I want it to replace all placeholders that are within the indexes that have z, so it can show as " - - z z - "**

How can I find the duplicated elements in a array and replace them?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the length of the random word, checking each letter to see if it is the chosen letter.  If it is, replace the character at that index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < randomChosenWord.length; i++) {
  if(randomChosenWord[i] === this.letter){
    lettersChosen.splice(i, 1, this.letter);
  }
}
```

This would replace the line

```
lettersChosen.splice(randomChosenWord.indexOf(this.letter), 1, this.letter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short way of doing it:

```
lettersChosen.split('').map(function (letter, i) {
    return randomChosenWord[i] === this.letter ? this.letter : letter;
}).join('')
```

Split the lettersChosen into an array of individual letters, iterate through them using array.map and replace all matching letters, then join into a string again.

Comment: You answer is way cooler than mine.  +1

Comment: Yay! Bonus points for being cool (but slow, as in slow to respond... and probably code-wise when I think about it, which shouldn't be a problem for hangman, I guess)! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line: `if (randomChosenWord.includes(this.letter)) {` to a while loop.